# CDI : @Specializes bean can replace only one bean?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

```
Env:
    Wildfly 9.0.1
    Weld 2.2.14
```

Going by CDI spec and the way @Specializes works, seems to me that a @Specializes bean can only replace '**a**' bean/implementation and not '**some**' beans/implementations.

I find this strange given the flexibility that interfaces and qualifiers provide.

Let me give the scenario via example code:

Bean classes:

```
interface Animal {
  public String getName();
}

@Siamese
public class Cat implements Animal {
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "Siamese";
  }
}

@Labrador
public class Dog implements Animal {
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "Labrador";
  }
}
```

Injection points:

```
@Siamese
@Inject
private Animal cat;

@Labrador
@Inject
private Animal dog;
```

Given the code, my intention is to provide one @Specializes mock bean that can be injected into both the injection points listed above. Here is the mock bean

```
@Alternative
@Specializes
public class MockAnimal implements Animal {
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "Mock Animal";
  }
}
```

But this seems impossible as the MockBean must "extend" whichever bean it needs to specialize.

Wanted to check with you guys if there is a work around other than creating MockDog and MockCat.

Thanks in advance,

Rakesh

Comment: I guess you could try to annotate your mock with both qualifiers Siamese and Labrador. In that case the mock bean would be elligible on both injection points.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, what you would want to use is only `@Alternative` without `@Specializes`, and add all qualifiers you want your bean to be injected with. `@Specializes` is only necessary when you want the new bean completely cover the old bean without copying its qualifiers, and even for injection points that use `@Any` annotation.

Solution for you example would then be:

```
@Alternative
@Labrador
@Siamese
public class MockAnimal implements Animal {
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "Mock Animal";
  }
}
```

The only injection point, where this would not cover `Cat` and `Dog` beans, would be an injection point with `@Any`, like this:

```
@Any
Instace<Animal> allAnimals;
```

This would list all 3 implementations of Animal, even with the alternative enabled. But it seems that this is not your concern.